# annotated drawing must remain same position where it was done in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, image, drawing

i used WPF application and i have drawn a line on a dicom image.but my problem is when i resize main window, line positions are changed. it wont persist on the place where i drawn. i have tried with pointtoscreen method and translatepoint method. but didnt work. what is the correct way to do this.

i used two wpf image controls. one is to display the dicom image and other is on top of it to draw annotation.following is my wpf xaml code.

```
<Border x:Name="Border" ClipToBounds="True">
<Grid>
<Image x:Name="ImageTileViewer"
           Margin="-234"
           Source="{Binding CurrentImage}"
           Stretch="None"
           StretchDirection="DownOnly" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>

    <Grid Name="AnnotationImageGrid">
                <Image Name="AnnotationImage" Stretch="None" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: Before Resize]

[image: After Resize]

Comment: It looks like you have a window and put the two images in the window.  Normally the trick is to add a panel to the window so the reference point is always the same.  The problem is when you center the main image the line doesn't automatically move.  If you notice the center of the image is exactly the same in both pictures and the line length is the same length.  The reference of a image is usually the upper left corner.  By putting both the line and image in a panel makes it easier to keep the reference point the same when centering.

Comment: thank you jdweng.do you have any sample ?

Comment: @jdweng i couldn't tell you that, when resizing the main window i override the SizeChanged event of AnnotationImageGrid. in there i scale second image control (AnnotationImage). as follows -----------------------------------TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)_currentTileControl.AnnotationImage.RenderTransform;
                ScaleTransform st = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];
                st.ScaleX = factor;
                st.ScaleY = factor;

Comment: Usually an image has a Top, Left, Width, Height which are in pixels.  So you have  can keep the images centered the line doesn't have to move, but the length of the line may need to change.  If you double the size of the image the length of line would be half.

Comment: @jdweng i came up with this mention bellow.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="canDrawing" Height="450" Width="800"
        MouseMove="canDrawing_MouseMove_NotDown"
        MouseDown="canDrawing_MouseDown">
        <Image Name="imgTrash" 
               StretchDirection="DownOnly" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Source="C:\Users\Chaithika\Downloads\after_resize.PNG" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>

public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TransformGroup group = new TransformGroup();

        ScaleTransform xform = new ScaleTransform();
        group.Children.Add(xform);

        TranslateTransform tt = new TranslateTransform();
        group.Children.Add(tt);

        imgTrash.RenderTransform = group;
        canDrawing.RenderTransform = group;
    }

  private void Window1_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
   var width = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewSize.Width);
   var height = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewSize.Height);

        double factor = Math.Min((width / imgTrash.ActualWidth), (height /  imgTrash.ActualHeight));
if (width >= imgTrash.ActualWidth && height >= imgTrash.ActualHeight)
{
    factor = 1;
}

TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)imgTrash.RenderTransform;
ScaleTransform st = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];


st.ScaleX = factor;
st.ScaleY = factor;


TransformGroup transformGroup2 = (TransformGroup)canDrawing.RenderTransform;
ScaleTransform st2 = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup2.Children[0];
st2.ScaleX = factor;
st2.ScaleY = factor;
```

}